# CSS transition of the transform property but with different modes

Tags: css

I have a button that has a scale and a rotation effect on it when its hovered on. I want to achieve these effects but with different durations.
Basically, I want to achieve something like this

```
.button {    
   transition: transform 0.1s;/* scale should be .1s and rotate should be .5s*/
}
.button:hover {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 4px rgb(105, 64, 64);
   transform: scale(1.111, 1.111) rotate(360deg);
}
```

Any short hand way of doing this? Is this even possible?

conceptual example

```
.button{
  transition[scale]: .1s;
  transition[rotate]: .5s
}
```

edit: actually, the already present solutons are for 2 different properties (`height` and `opacity`), while mine is on a single property (`transform`) , but `transform` has 2 modes, `rotate` and `scale`, which need to be animated with different timing.
I need `transform:rotate` with `.5s` and `transform:scale` with `.1s`

edit 2: someone mentioned the use of animation, so this is what I did

```css
@keyframes anim1 {
        0%{
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        50%{
          transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        100%{
          transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
      }
      @keyframes anim2 {
        0%{
          transform: scale(1,1);
        }
        50%{
          transform: scale(1.111,1.111);
        }
        100%{
          transform: scale(1,1);
        }
      }
.button{
animation: anim1 3s ease-in-out, anim2 5s ease-in-out;
}
```

This method firstly autoplays the animation, and secondly and more importantly, the second animation overrides the first and I am left with only scale and no rotation. But If someone can make this code work, its great either way !

Comment: actually, The above solution is for 2 different properties (height and opacity), while mine is on a single property (transform) , but transform has 2 modes, rotate and scale, which need to be animated with different timing. But I do thank you for your response :)

Comment: use animation instead of transform or consider nested containers

Comment: Not possible as yet. Different transforms are proposed but not yet adopted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this can be achieved with wrapping containers.  It is not the desired behavior you stated of using a single container, but unfortunately as of Dec 2020 that syntax is not supported.  Below is a rough POC showing this in action:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.animate-scale {    
   transition: transform 0.1s;
}
.animate-scale:hover {    
   transform: scale(1.111, 1.111);
}
.animate-rotate {    
   transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.animate-rotate:hover {    
   transform: rotate(360deg);
}


.button {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 4px rgb(105, 64, 64);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="animate-scale">
    <div class="animate-rotate">
      <span class="button">
        Hover me!
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is useful in achieving my effect nonetheless. I did not expect that the syntax is straight up not supported as of now. But anyway, thank you for the solution.